# Variable not defined issue with a simple GUI program

Tags: python

I'm following the examples in our text and I can't see any issue with the code that would cause this particular issue, it is saying lotnumsred isn't defined and I can't figure out why. Keeps returning NameError: name 'lotnumsred' is not defined.

```py
from tkinter import *
import random
def pickrando():
    addnumred = random.randint(1, 35)
    lotnumsred.set(addnumred)
window = Tk()
window.title("Powerball")
producebutton = Button(window, text = "Produce a Drawing", command = pickrando())
producebutton.grid(padx=10, pady = 10, row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 4, sticky = NSEW)
lotnumsred = StringVar()
lotnumswhite = StringVar()
whiteentry = Entry(window, state = "readonly", textvariable = lotnumswhite, width = 10)
whiteentry.grid(padx = 5, pady = 5, row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W)
redentry = Entry(window, state = "readonly", textvariable = lotnumsred, width = 3)
redentry.grid(padx = 5, pady = 5, row = 2, column = 1, sticky = W)
whitelabel = Label(window, text = "White balls:")
whitelabel.grid(padx = 2, pady = 5, row = 1, column = 0, sticky = E)
redlabel = Label(window, text = "Red ball:")
redlabel.grid(padx = 2, pady = 5, row = 2, column = 0, sticky = E)

window.mainloop()
```

Should be putting a random number in the entry field for the red number, I know that white isn't in the code atm I removed it because it was originally having the same problem and I thought it was something else. So I don't expect the white numbers to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from tkinter import *
import random
def pickrando():
    addnumred = random.randint(1, 35)
    lotnumsred.set(addnumred)
window = Tk()
window.title("Powerball")
producebutton = Button(window, text = "Produce a Drawing", command = pickrando())
producebutton.grid(padx=10, pady = 10, row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 4, sticky = NSEW)
lotnumsred = StringVar()
lotnumswhite = StringVar()
whiteentry = Entry(window, state = "readonly", textvariable = lotnumswhite, width = 10)
whiteentry.grid(padx = 5, pady = 5, row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W)
redentry = Entry(window, state = "readonly", textvariable = lotnumsred, width = 3)
redentry.grid(padx = 5, pady = 5, row = 2, column = 1, sticky = W)
whitelabel = Label(window, text = "White balls:")
whitelabel.grid(padx = 2, pady = 5, row = 1, column = 0, sticky = E)
redlabel = Label(window, text = "Red ball:")
redlabel.grid(padx = 2, pady = 5, row = 2, column = 0, sticky = E)

window.mainloop()
```

You are accessing `lotnumsred` in the function `pickrando()`. So that means `lotnumsred` must be defined before you call that function. But `pickrando()` is supposed to be called whenever a Button is created. But what's actually happening is its being called on line 8

That is why you are getting the error, since `pickrando()` is being called, before the 10th line where `lotnumsred` is being definied.

You can change it by doing `command = pickrando`

Comment: This doesn't fix the right problem.  The real issue is that `pickrando()` was being called when creating the Button, rather than when it is clicked:  changing it to `command = pickrando` specifies the *function itself* (rather than its return value) as the button's action.

Comment: @jasonharper Thanks for the feedback, is this better?

Comment: Thanks you guys this fixed the issue, changing it to pickrando instead of pickrando() basically fixed the whole thing. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @DU Your welcome, please accept the answer if it helped